# WCF Streaming - Limiting speed

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-streaming

This is a severe problem in my application for some months with out finding any good solution.
I noticed that C# manage the way Stream class is streaming in WCF, without considering my configuration.

Firstly, I have a class that inherit from FileStream so I can watch how much was read until now from the client side at anytime:

```
public class FileStreamWatching : FileStream
    {
        /// <summary>        
        /// how much was read until now        
        /// </summary>        
        public long _ReadUntilNow { get; private set; }
        public FileStreamWatching(string Path, FileMode FileMode, FileAccess FileAccess)
            : base(Path, FileMode, FileAccess)
        {
            this._ReadUntilNow = 0;
        }
        public override int Read(byte[] array, int offset, int count)
        {
            int ReturnV = base.Read(array, offset, count);
            //int ReturnV = base.Read(array, offset, count);
            if (ReturnV > 0)
            {
                _ReadUntilNow += ReturnV;
                Console.WriteLine("Arr Lenght: " + array.Length);
                Console.WriteLine("Read: " + ReturnV);
                Console.WriteLine("****************************");
            }
            return ReturnV;
        }
    }
```

Secondly, below is my service method of reading the client's stream that contain the file.
My main problem is that FileStreamWatching.Read does not start for each time I summon it from this method below, instead FileStreamWatching.Read start one time for each X times I call it.. Strange.

***Look at the out put later**

```
    public void Get_File_From_Client(Stream MyStream)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Upload\" + "Chat.rar", FileMode.Create))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
            int bytes = 0;
            while ((bytes = MyStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
                fs.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
```

**This is the output at the client side for each time FileStreamWatching.Read is activated:(Remmber the buffer lenght is only 1000!)**

Arr Lenght: 256,
Read: 256

---

Arr Lenght: 4096,
Read: 4096

---

Arr Lenght: 65536,
Read: 65536

---

Arr Lenght: 65536,
Read: 65536

---

Arr Lenght: 65536,
Read: 65536

---

Arr Lenght: 65536,
Read: 65536

---

....Until the file transfare is complete.

**Problems:**

1. The Lenght of the buffer I brought to the read method isnt 256/4096/65536. It is 1000.
2. The Read from the FileStreamWatching class does not start each time I call it from the service.

**My goals:**

1. Controling on how much I reacive from the client for each read.
2. The FileStreamWatching.Read will start each time I call it from the service.

**My Client configuration:**

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IJob" transferMode="Streamed"/>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/Request2" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IJob" contract="ServiceReference1.IJob"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IJob" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**My service configuration** (There is no configuration file here):

```
        BasicHttpBinding BasicHttpBinding1 = new BasicHttpBinding();
        BasicHttpBinding1.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;
        //
        BasicHttpBinding1.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
        BasicHttpBinding1.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 1000;
        BasicHttpBinding1.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 1000;
        BasicHttpBinding1.MaxBufferSize = 1000;
        //
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(JobImplement), new Uri("http://localhost:8080"));
        //
        ServiceMetadataBehavior behavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        behavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        //
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
        ServiceThrottlingBehavior throttle = new ServiceThrottlingBehavior();
        throttle.MaxConcurrentCalls = 1;
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(throttle);
        //
        //
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IJob), BasicHttpBinding1, "Request2");
        host.Open();
```

Comment: MyStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) - shouldn't the offset increment after each call?

Comment: @Tisho the application probably does change offset each call.  Whether it does or not does not influence Stav's question at this point in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**re: why 256/4K/65535?**

I see two possibilities going on here:

- The base `FileStream` is doing its own internal buffering.  It may be internally calling `read(array,offset,length)` to fill its internal buffer, then passing back the portion you asked for.  The internal calls end up being recursive, until it has read the entire file.  Then your override stops displaying anything.
- There are other `stream.read()` signatures you don't show as being overridden. If any code path ends up calling one of the other `read` methods, then your counts will be off.

**re: MyStream not starting over each time**

Is the `MyStream` argument ever disposed? or is it reused for a new stream?  Your code only "restarts" in the constructor, so be *sure* the object is disposed and re-constructed when you change incoming streams.

You can test for the recursive EOF case by also displaying something when EOF is reached.

You can test for unexpected recursion if you add static variables counting both the application calls to `MyStream.Read` and the method entry/exit.  If they don't match, then `FileStream` is making internal (accidentally recursive) calls.

-Jesse